# Value of parent input

Tags: javascript, jquery

From select name change[] val(), I would like to get input from it's parent input id champion[] with JQuery but I'm getting

> 'undefined' error

```
<div id="p_scents">
        <p>    
            <label for="p_scnts">
                <input type="text" id="champion[]" size="20" list="champions" value=""  placeholder="Enter Champion's name">
                <datalist id="champions"></datalist>
                <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add General Change</a><a></a>
                <a href="#" id="addSpell"> Add Spell</a><a></a>
                   <a>
                        <p>
                            <select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val()"></select>
                            <label for="var" readonly="true">
                                 <input type="text" id="championSpell[]">
                                 <br>
                                 <textarea type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_2" value="" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
                                 <select></select>
                            </label>
                            <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add Change</a>
                            <a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Spell</a></p></a>
            </label>
        </p>
</div>
```

var championName = $("#change").closest('input').val();

Comment: Why are you wrapping bunch of form controls with an anchor? Nested `p` elements? Nested `a` elements? That markup cries for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)"></select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function val(elm) {
  var championName = $(elm).closest("label").find("input").val();

  alert('champion name is ' + championName);
}
```

Comment: var championName = $("#change").closest('input').val(); thats the code I'm trying to execute

Comment: that won't work because `#champion[]` is not a direct parent of `#change[]`

Comment: The code is dynamically created that is why I need to use closest function somehow because using it your way it will always show me championName from the first input on all the inputs

Comment: I was assuming `id` is unique. If elements are dynamic, it's better to traverse using `.class`